# how to get a value in python : HTML: <span class="label">Google</span>

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to get the "Google" value?

I have used get.attribute method, but it shows "None". However when I used get.attribute('innerHTMl'), it provides the whole element:

```
 <span class="label">Google</span>
```

My code:

```
a = d.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="label"]')
b =a.get_attribute('value')
print(b)
```

Output: `None`

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1:** `@` seems to have been missed out in your XPath expression. It should be as below: (Notice the `@` just before `class`)

```
//*[@class="label"]
```

**Issue 2:** You cannot use `get_attribute('value')` as there is no `value` attribute in the desired element's node.

You have to use `.text`. So code should be:

```
a = d.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="label"]')
b =a.text
print(b)
```

Using Selenium's [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/), code will be as below:

```
a = WebDriverWait(d, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='label']")))
b = a.text
print(b)
```

Imports required for Explicit Waits:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as
```

Comment: This code works:  a = WebDriverWait(d, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='label']")))
b = a.text
print(b)

Comment: Glad it worked. Accept the answer if it has resolved your issue. That way question will be not left unanswered.